# Schema validation

Tags: cascading, scalding

H,

I am looking for any example for schema validation for data.

Is it possible to do using cascading or scalding.

For example

Name:String , Age:Int

We say our data should confirm to above schema

then we can validate if data really is of that type

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Scala, you can declare your type:

```
case class Record(name: String, age: Int)
```

then suppose your data is in CSV, use the Scalding Type-safe API:

```
val lines: TypedPipe[String] = TypedPipe.from(TextLine("data.csv"))
val records: TypedPipe[Record] = lines.map{ line =>
  line.split(",").toList match {
    case List(name, age) => Record(name, age.toInt)
    case _ => throw new BadSchemaException(line)
  }
}
```

If you want to trap bad records and do not fail your job, see addTrap method in RichPipe class.

Comment: This approach will have any limitations due to tuple size limitation ?

Answer (score 0):

Traps are not intended for application flow control. Setting a boolean field based on your application validation rules and filtering out the bad records is a better approach. I recommend you to read:

http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.6/userguide/html/ch08s03.html
http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.6/userguide/html/ch11s09.html#handling-bad-data